# How to add annotation on main constructor parameters in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection, kotlin-reflect

Having the following class:

```
data class TestMsg(
    @Parse(";") 
    val someArray: Array<String>
)
```

And trying to get the annotation with

```
TestMsg::class.primaryConstructor!!.parameters.forEach{
    println(it.findAnnotation<Parse>())
}
```

There is no annotation found. I had to move the annotation front of the parameter for make it working

```
data class TestMsg(
    @Parse(";") val someArray: Array<String>
)
```

is it a parsing error of jetbrains or is it the normal behavior?

---

**EDIT**

You can find the annotation right here:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY, AnnotationTarget.TYPE_PARAMETER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Parse(
    val delimiter: String
)
```

Comment: please add annotation implementations

Comment: works fine on  - kotlin-reflect 1.3.50 , 
kotlin 1.3.50

Comment: I added the annotation

Comment: well I'm using 1.3.41

Comment: I still have the bug with 1.3.50

Comment: you should try adding a parameter before someArray

Comment: I tasted it before you edit and add the annotation, only with marker  annotation without @Target and Retention

Comment: You're right, it's working without it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY to  AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.VALUE_PARAMETER, AnnotationTarget.TYPE_PARAMETER)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class Parse(
    val delimiter: String
)
```